# Computing Confidence Intervals for a Pass/Fail rate

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution

I'm trying to determine to within a specified confidence whether or not a certain software component has improved versus some previous version.  I have pass/fail rates for the component for the previous version as well as the current version.

I initially tried to use a simple mean and normal distribution to estimate the confidence, but this breaks down for components that are near 0% or 100% pass rates.

I built this model that I would like to use, which uses binomial coefficients to estimate the expected probability of the outcome for all possible pass/fail ratios:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eov4gl1ue1

To summarize, I'm trying to find the values for `n` for which the following sum reaches the specified thresholds:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{p+f}{p+f \choose n}\theta^{n}\left(1-\theta\right)^{\left(p+f\right)-n}$$

Where $\theta$ is the mean or some other estimated value.

Here is my current implementation and its output:
https://gist.github.com/otac0n/71a7c33ef7311fcd32fce9098c4b678a

```
pass=10, fail=2:
    83.33% (58.33%-100.00% @95.00%)
pass=100, fail=20:
    83.33% (75.83%-90.00% @95.00%)
pass=1000, fail=200:
    83.33% (81.17%-85.50% @95.00%)
pass=10000, fail=2000:
    (exception thrown)
```

This works well for small values.  However, I am running into integer/double overflows with my current implementation for larger values.

Is there a better method for calculating the values shown for large inputs, specifically the interval e.g. `75.83%-90.00%`?

Comment: Maybe this link has the answers for you https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344565/how-to-calculate-confidence-interval-for-proportions-with-small-numerators-and-l/344567#344567

Comment: @siddharthapachhai It doesn't seem so, since it uses a pure $\pm$, which will run into the problems near 0 and 1, won't it? If you disagree, please explain in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just looking for a confidence interval for a proportion?

There are different methods.  The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) has a few. Among them, Clopper–Pearson and Agresti–Coull.

In R, the common function [binom.test](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.3/topics/binom.test) uses the Clopper-Pearson method.

The [BinomCI function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DescTools/versions/0.99.19/topics/BinomCI) in the DescTools package includes various methods, including Wilson, and Agresti-Coull.  There are references given at the link there.

Also note that you can calculate a confidence interval for the difference in two proportions.  This may be advantageous for what you are trying to do.  See, for example, the [PropCIs package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/PropCIs/versions/0.3-0/topics/wald2ci) for a reference.

Comment: Although, after a bit of research including a glance at Agresti, Alan; Coull, Brent A. (1998). "Approximate is better than 'exact' for interval estimation of binomial proportions", I think I'm best served to use the Wilson score interval with continuity correction method from Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

With the proportion confidence interval it only means that if you have a large data set you can use

$$p \pm z_{\alpha/2} \sqrt {\hat p\hat q/n}$$, 
So if you have a 100% it means 100 $\pm$ 0, which means 100, and for 0 it would mean zero.This is because proportion of sucess = 100%, proportion of faliure = 100 - p.sucess.

On the other hand you could maybe try a logistic regression to obtain all probabilities for each observation, and then do a confidence interval on the estimated probabilities. When you estimate the probabilities they should be between 0 < $\pi$< 1, so not touching the ends. Then you can get a CI on them. But regression works differently and inferences will be on each observation.